# Opening large Json file blocks UI

Tags: python, json, multithreading, pyside

```
class SharedData(QtCore.QObject):
   def __init__(self):
      super(SharedData, self).__init__()

      self.loader = None

      self.mutex = QtCore.QMutex()
      self.loader_created = QtCore.QWaitCondition()


class Bungie(QtCore.QObject):
   denied = QtCore.Signal()
   authenticated = QtCore.Signal()

   def __init__(self, data):
      super(Bungie, self).__init__()

      self.data = data
      self.bungie = bungie.Bungie()

   @QtCore.Slot(str, str)
   def login(self, username, password):
      ...
            try:
               self.bungie.login(username, password)
            except bungie.InvalidCredentials:
               ...
               self.denied.emit()
            else:
               self.authenticated.emit()

               with util.Locker(self.data.mutex):
                  self.data.loader = loader.Loader(self.bungie)
                  self.data.loader_created.wakeAll()
      ...


class Loader(QtCore.QObject):
   def __init__(self, data):
      super(Loader, self).__init__()

      self.data = data

   @QtCore.Slot()
   def start(self):
      with util.Locker(self.data.mutex):
         if self.data.loader is None:
            self.data.loader_created.wait(self.data.mutex)

      with util.Locker(self.data.mutex):
         if self.data.loader:
            self.data.loader.loadDefinitions()


class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
   login = QtCore.Signal(str, str)

   def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)

      # UI 
      ...

      self.data = SharedData()

      self.bungie_thread = QtCore.Thread(parent=self)
      self.bungie = Bungie(self.data)
      self.bungie.moveToThread(self.bungie_thread)

      self.loader_thread = QtCore.Thread(parent=self)
      self.loader = Loader(self.data)
      self.loader.moveToThread(self.loader_thread)

      self.login.connect(self.bungie.login)

      self.loader_thread.started.connect(self.loader.start)

      self.bungie_thread.start()
      self.loader_thread.start()
```

And here is what *loadDefinitions* does:

```
   def loadDefinitions(self):
      if self.item_def is None:
         with open("manifest/DestinyInventoryItemDefinition_hashkey.json",
                   "r") as fin_json:
            self.item_def = json.load(fin_json)

      if self.bucket_def is None:
         with open("manifest/DestinyInventoryBucketDefinition_hashkey.json",
                   "r") as fin_json:
            self.bucket_def = json.load(fin_json)

      if self.stat_def is None:
         with open("manifest/DestinyStatDefinition_hashkey.json",
                   "r") as fin_json:
            self.stat_def = json.load(fin_json)
```

So what happens is I create two workers passing in some data to their constructors and create a thread for each of them and move them to their respective threads. I start the loader as soon as the thread is started and it waits. The other thread will wake it and then it runs *loadDefinitions*. The problem seems to be the first *json.load()* in *loadDefinitions*. It opens and deserializes a ~8.75MB json file. The other two are only like ~9KB. During this the UI freezes up - what am I missing here? Why does this happen?

Thanks.

Edit:
If I replace *loadDefinitions* with:

```
      numbers = []
      for _ in xrange(1000000):
         numbers.append(random.randint(1, 101))
```

The UI does not block. The issue seems to be with *json.load*

Because the file is so large I've just opted to loading it before the UI is shown.

Comment: looks like your login is waiting for the same lock?

Comment: you mean the mutex? [wait](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwaitcondition.html#wait) will unlock the mutex and then wait on the condition.